# Binary Search Tree validation without max value

Tags: validation, binary-search-tree

I've build an algorithm to validate if a tree is a Binary Search Tree or not.
It works for most cases, but for some specific cases which should validate false, it is validating true.

Here is my algorithm:

```cs
public bool IsBinarySearchTree(BinaryTreeNode root)
{
    if (root == null) return true;

    if (
        (root.Left != null && root.Value.CompareTo(root.Left.Value) < 0) ||
        (root.Right != null && root.Value.CompareTo(root.Right.Value) > 0) ||
        ((root.Left != null && root.Right != null) && root.Left.Value.CompareTo(root.Right.Value) > 0)
    )
        return false;
    
    return IsBinarySearchTree(root.Left) && IsBinarySearchTree(root.Right);
}
```

I saw some code out there using a min and max value in this recursive approach, but I am not using here. Can someone help me to understand why this code fails in some scenarios?

Here is a scenario where it should validate as false, but it is validating as true:

```cs
[Test]
public void OnIsBinarySearchTree_ShouldReturnTrue()
{
    // Arrange
    TreesAndGraphs.BinaryTreeNode rootNode = new TreesAndGraphs.BinaryTreeNode(10);
    rootNode.Left = new TreesAndGraphs.BinaryTreeNode(8);
    rootNode.Right = new TreesAndGraphs.BinaryTreeNode(12);
    rootNode.Left.Left = new TreesAndGraphs.BinaryTreeNode(6);
    rootNode.Left.Right = new TreesAndGraphs.BinaryTreeNode(11);
    rootNode.Right.Left = new TreesAndGraphs.BinaryTreeNode(11);
    rootNode.Right.Right = new TreesAndGraphs.BinaryTreeNode(13);

    var treesAndGraphs = new TreesAndGraphs();

    // Act
    bool isBST = treesAndGraphs.IsBinarySearchTree(rootNode);

    // Assert
    Assert.That(isBST, Is.True);
}
```

I am using C# with NUnit to perform this test.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is checking whether the left child of a node has a greater value than the node itself, or whether the right child of a node has a less value than the node itself. If neither is true for any node, then you conclude the binary search tree is valid.

But this is not enough to validate a binary search tree. Even when all nodes pass the above test, you can still have an invalid binary search tree. This is the visualisation of the tree for which your code returns the wrong result:

```
         __10__
        /      \
       8        12
      / \      /  \
     6   11  11    13
```

As you can see, every left child is less than its parent, and every right child is greater than its parent, so that looks fine, but still the left-most 11 is violating the rules:

In a binary search tree *all nodes* in the left *subtree* of a parent node should have a value that is less than, or equal to, the parent node. Node 11 violates this rule, and it is clear your code does not detect this.